# Query mongo document based on its subdocument using $exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to fetch records from mongo using mongoose.
I have document called *projects* that has sub-document *work*. *work* has *user*, *to* and *from* properties. I want to fetch the document that has specific *user*, and doesn't have *to* value set.

So far i tried:

```
models.project.findOne {'work.user': user,'work.to':{$exists: false}},
  (err, data) -> # data is always null, no error.
```

It seems that if just one of objects in work contains property 'to' then $exists: equals to true. Is there a way to do this?

Also here is same code in JS if you prefer:

```
models.project.findOne({
  'work.user': user,
  'work.to': {
    $exists: false
  }
}, function(err, data) {});
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$elemMatch` in this case, which will return results only when specific `user` matched and doesn't have `to` value set **in the same array element**:

```
models.project.users.findOne({
"work" : { $elemMatch: {"user":user, "to": {$exists: false}}}
}, function(err, data) {});
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use "null" for this case instead of $exists

```
models.project.findOne({
  'work.user': user,
  'work.to': null
}, function(err, data) {});
```